# How can I change row information in a Query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rows

I'm using Postgres and I'd like to know how to change row information within a query, Let's say I have a column called `Numbers` and it's got rows going `1,2,3,4,5` how could I edit the information in those rows? let's say I want the query to display  `1,1,1,1,5` how would I write in a query that each row should be changed to 1 unless it's 5? Again it's only to change it within the Query, I'm not trying to do an `UPDATE` I realize how newbish this is on my part but I couldn't find this on google.

Comment: I'm going to make my scenario more realistic, it looks like this: Numbers, Letters, Symbols <- let's say those three are columns, and I'm Selecting them all in my Query, but I just want to change the numbers.

Comment: Obviously `6` is going to get transformed to `1`, but what about `10` and how many rows are being selected?  What larger problem are you attempting to solve, that you're trying this - there may be better ways of looking for a solution.

Comment: This scenario is a bit complicated but basically I have a view that looks like this:

columns: `VehicleID, Airplanes, Cars, Boats`

Awright now my query needs to select the Cars and the Boats so it's gonna look like this.

`SELECT Cars, Boats`

but here's what I need to do, the Cars column rows looks like this: **Red Blue Yellow**

I want them to load up as all Red if they aren't Blue so it should look like this:

**Red Blue Red**

how can I use `CASE`, if I'm selecting 2 columns? it seems like `CASE` only works when selecting only the Column that I want to modify.
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Numbers <> 5 THEN 1 ELSE Numbers END
FROM table
```

See [9.12. Conditional Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html)

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE" at character 238

I'm not sure if this is because I'm selecting multiple columns at the same time I'm trying to change that column.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was just silly and forgot to include "," in the select statement.